# I have created an XML layout, and would like to display animation as well. How would I achieve that?

Tags: android, xml

In my app I set up the view I wanted, and got the schematics working, but decided I wanted to try my hand at adding very basic animation to it. In the tutorials I have seen, the process is to create a new class and set it to setContentView, so that the new class is displayed. Is there a way I can display my XML, as well as animations? If so, how would I go about setting that up?

Edit: I figured out my problem. I didn't realize I could add a custom view inside of my xml. In my confusion, it seemed like I had to pick between either a custom view or my xml view.

Comment: This question is entirely too broad.  Plus, you're taking the completely wrong approach.  Look up sprite sheets.  That might give you a pushin the right direction.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I guess I still don't quite grasp the concept of this. Lets say I had my xml display a few textviews and button, and then I wanted to animate something moving across the screen behind those, how would I set that up?

Comment: Again...  It's too broad a question.  If you do a google search for Sprite sheets (that's a start), you will find plenty of examples for how to animate things with cels.  And plenty of other examples that explain how to move things along the X and Y axis.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Oh sorry! My question isn't actually about the animation itself, but rather on how it's viewed. I can tell I'm not relaying my intentions as well as I would hope as I'm a little confused. From all I have seen with Sprite sheets, they seem to all have a custom view displayed. If I wanted to set up animation, would I have to scrap my xml and recreate it in a custom view, or could I keep my xml view, and make a separate view to animate?

Comment: No, don't use sprite sheets for Android xml layout animations. Just do a google search on Android layout animation tutorial, look at the published date of the tutorial you find to make sure it's current. If you want to feel inspired, look for youtube videos where Chet Haase is talking, he wrote the animation framework of Android.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I think I have figured out my issue, but would like to thank you as I can definitely use that in the future

Answer (score 1):

1 Get the view which you wanna set Animation in xml.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bg_iv);
```

2 you need to set Animation you want to xml in res/animation. the below codes are just example for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="2000"
/>
</set>
```

3 set your animation xml and start it.

```
   Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_tr);
   iv.setAnimation(anim);
```